# create time steps array in ruby on rails in 30 or 60 minute increments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I am creating a simple appointment keeper in Rails 4, and I need to create an array of times for the user to choose between a min/max.  The user can also choose if they are creating a 30 or 60 min appointment.

I tried to create the array like this

```
 def time_range
     return [] if time_start.blank? || time_end.blank?
    (time_start.to_time .. time_end.to_time).to_a
  end
```

but I keep getting the error

```
can't iterate from Time
```

I don't know how I could break this out into increments, either.

I'm just showing them as a list

```
  ul.list-unstyled
    - @meeting.time_range.each do |calendar_time|
      li 
        = calendar_time
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make use of [**`step`**](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-step)

```
(Time.now.to_i..1.day.from_now.to_i).step(30.minutes).each do |time|
    puts Time.at(time)
end
```

So the method will be

```
def time_range
  return [] if time_start.blank? || time_end.blank?
  (time_start.to_time.to_i..time_end.to_time.to_i)
end
```

And you can use it as

```
ul.list-unstyled
  - @meeting.time_range.step(30.minutes).each do |calendar_time|
    li 
      = Time.at(calendar_time)
```

Comment: hmm...I am getting this "undefined method `step' for #<Array:0x007f96039311d8>"

Comment: try removing `to_a` from `(time_start.to_time.to_i..time_end.to_time.to_i)`

Comment: that did it!  I didn't know step...somehow